# Apache Mahout: Creating similarities for taste_item_similarity table for the MySQLJDBCItemSimilarity class

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I've created a taste_preferences table with the user_id, item_id, and preference, but now I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the similarities and insert them into my taste_item_similarity table.

Here's the link to the [MySQLJDBCDataModel](http://apache.github.io/mahout/0.10.1/docs/mahout-integration/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/model/jdbc/MySQLJDBCDataModel.html) class which talks about the taste_preferences table, and here's a link to the [MySQLJDBCItemSimilarity](http://apache.github.io/mahout/0.10.1/docs/mahout-integration/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/jdbc/MySQLJDBCItemSimilarity.html) class which talks about the taste_item_similarity table.

Any help would be great!